# Cyanogenmod - What is "Notification mode"?

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications, vibration, profiles

I think I'm misunderstanding the profiles options in Cyanogenmod regarding notifications.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I would like all notifications to pop in the status bar, but only the phone and messaging ones should vibrate. At work, the phone & messages shouldn't  ring.

I've configured my profiles this way:

Group "Phone&Messaging" contains phone, messaging, email and gmail apps.

**Work:Phone&Messaging**

- Notification mode: on
- Ring mode: off
- Vibrate mode: on

**Work:Other**

- Notification mode: on
- Ring mode: off
- Vibrate mode: off

**Home:Phone&Messaging**

- Notification mode: on
- Ring mode: on
- Vibrate mode: on

**Home:Other**

- Notification mode: on
- Ring mode: off
- Vibrate mode: off

But some stupid notifications still vibrate (when I download an app on the Google Play Store, my phone vibrates during all the download duration).

So how should the "Notification mode" be used?

Comment: It vibrates while downloading? That sounds like a bug to be honest. What version are you using, is it a nightly release? Did you look on the thread for your device/ROM and see if it has been reported. I do love CM but the nightlies are sometimes riddled with bugs.

Answer (score 1):

"Notification mode" refers not to the notification bar, but the notification sounds. If you turn it off, then notification sounds will be off. Notifications in the notification bar will still show.

Some notifications still vibrating: sounds like the app developer implemented manual vibration instead of using notification settings.

Answer (score 0):

A ring vs. a notification is known to most, you may not have just thought about it. Notifications are shorter, dings, bells, tones, etc... where a ring is an actual ringtone, longer, usually a melody or song. With CM, you can of course choose your notification sound if you have a root browser, in /system/media/audio my ROM's bring up a list right in settings, but CM needs a rot Browser... I guess because they have `CMFileManager`